# how do i make fillstyle and stroke style work?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

```
//clear screen
function CLS() {
    draw.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
    draw.strokeStyle = "#ffffff"; //to white
    draw.rect(0, 0, 300, 150); //position 
    draw.stroke();
    draw.fill(); //draw it
}
//screen update
function UpdateScreen() {
    //draw ground
    draw.fillStyle = "#000000";
    draw.strokeStyle = "#000000"; //to black
    draw.rect(0, 100, 300, 25); //position    
    draw.stroke();
    draw.fill(); //draw it
    //draw guy
    draw.fillStyle = "#c7c7c7";
    draw.strokeStyle = "#c7c7c7"; //to grey
    draw.beginPath();
    draw.arc(guyX, guyY, 15, 0, 2 * Math.PI); //position
    draw.fill();
    draw.stroke(); //draw it
}
CLS();
UpdateScreen();
```

the color set for the white rectangle is using the black color from the next declaration, how do i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [beginPath()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/beginPath) method, before drawing all the shapes.

```
//clear screen
function CLS() {
    draw.beginPath();
    draw.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
    draw.strokeStyle = "#ffffff"; //to white
    draw.rect(0, 0, 300, 150); //position 
    draw.stroke();
    draw.fill(); //draw it
}
//screen update
function UpdateScreen() {
    //draw ground
    draw.beginPath();
    draw.fillStyle = "#000000";
    draw.strokeStyle = "#000000"; //to black
    draw.rect(0, 100, 300, 25); //position    
    draw.stroke();
    draw.fill(); //draw it
    //draw guy
    draw.beginPath();
    draw.fillStyle = "#c7c7c7";
    draw.strokeStyle = "#c7c7c7"; //to grey
    draw.arc(guyX, guyY, 15, 0, 2 * Math.PI); //position
    draw.fill();
    draw.stroke(); //draw it
}
CLS();
UpdateScreen();
```